# unable to composer update while installing Magento

Tags: magento2, composer

```
 magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.3].
```

getting above error messages while updating composer

Comment: Check the @Anar answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408604/php7-install-ext-dom-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occur because it won't fulfill Magento requirement's.

Before you install `Magento 2`, make sure your system meets the following requirements so that it won't throw any error:

```
 - PDO/MySQL
 - mbstring
 - mcrypt
 - mhash
 - simplexml
 - gd2, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both
 - soap
```

For PHP 7.0, you can use these commands:

```
 1. sudo apt-get update

 2. sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl
    php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-openssl php7.0-zip php7.0-soap

 3. sudo service apache2 restart
```

I hope this information help thanks.